# mediawiki: getting the pages in a given category

Tags: xml, api, mediawiki

using the mediawiki API, I can list the pages  in a given category. For example:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Physics

returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<api>
  <query>
    <categorymembers>
      <cm pageid="22939" ns="0" title="Physics" />
      <cm pageid="24489" ns="0" title="Outline of physics" />
      <cm pageid="1653925" ns="100" title="Portal:Physics" />
      <cm pageid="3445246" ns="0" title="Glossary of classical physics" />
      <cm pageid="22950086" ns="0" title="Britney Spears&#039; Guide to Semiconductor Physics" />
      <cm pageid="2129107" ns="14" title="Category:Fundamental physics concepts" />
      <cm pageid="4769321" ns="0" title="Timeline of fundamental physics discoveries" />
      <cm pageid="694942" ns="14" title="Category:Physicists" />
      <cm pageid="1198" ns="0" title="Acoustics" />
      <cm pageid="1913676" ns="14" title="Category:Applied and interdisciplinary physics" />
    </categorymembers>
  </query>
  <query-continue>
    <categorymembers cmcontinue="Atomic, molecular, and optical physics|" />
  </query-continue>
</api>
```

I now want to limit my query to only one MW namespace. I have tried to use the **cmnamespace** parameter. But

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Physics&cmnamespace=0

returns the *same* result. How should I use this namespace parameter ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a bug in the code running on English Wikipedia - your syntax works fine for me on slightly older versions of MediaWiki.

Comment: Thanks joshua, I've forwarded my question to the mw mailing list. I'll validate your answer if it is a bug (and it should be a bug :-) )